# @ComponentScan for every package in project

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-annotations

Is it possible to let `@ComponentScan` work on whole Spring Boot project? Now when I create a new package, I need to add it into `@ComponenScan` annotation otherwise beans won't be found. If it's possible to allow to search everywhere in project can it cause performance problems or any other issues?

```
Example:
first component StorageRoom\backend\src\main\java\com.storeage (here is main class with @ComponentScan annotation)
second component StorageRoom\backend\src\main\java\security
third component StorageRoom\backend\src\main\java\component3
```

Comment: you can add ComponentScan on the top-most package and will discover all packages and subpackages

Answer (score 1):

`@ComponentScan` without arguments tells Spring to scan the current package and all of its sub-packages.
So for your problem, I would recommend that you should have your main class at the root of the application and then annotate it with `@ComponentScan` there.
Something like here -
`StorageRoom\backend\src\main\java\SpringBootApplicationMain.java`
Find more here: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-component-scanning